# Qsort a char array in c

Tags: arrays, c, char, qsort

```
enum rarity
{
    common,
    uncommon,
    rare,
    mythic
};

struct card
{
    unsigned int id;
    char* name;
    char* cost;
    unsigned int converted_cost;
    char* type;
    char* text;
    char* stats;
    enum rarity rarity;
} card_t ;
```

I have 4 entries in my card struct. For example,
card[0]->name = "Stolen by the Fae", card[1]->name = "Eternal Isolation",
card[2]->name = "Corpse Knight", card[3]->name = "Orzhov Enforcer".

```
qsort(cards, cardsaccum , sizeof(char), cmpname);
```

In my qsort(), I think I'm putting in the correct parameters. My cardsaccum = 4, sizeof(char) is set because I'm checking the size of the name, then calling cmpname which sorts the names in order.

```
int cmpname (const void *pa, const void *pb) {
const card_t *p1 = pa;
const card_t *p2 = pb;
return strcmp(p1->name, p2->name);}
```

After the qsort(), my sorted entries are only the last entry read which is Orzhov Enforcer.

I don't understand why this is happening and was wondering if anyone could help explain why this is happening. Below is some of my code to better follow what I'm doing.

Comment: I'm not going to read all that code. It cannot possibly all be relevant. Instead, please explain to us why you are passing `sizeof(char)` to `qsort`. What is your logic there?

Answer (score 1):

```
qsort(cards, cardsaccum , sizeof(char), cmpname);
```

`cards` is of type `card_t **`, so each entry of the array is a `card_t *`.  It's not an array of `char`.  Thus the third argument to `qsort`, which specifies the size of each array element, should be `sizeof(card_t *)`, not `sizeof(char)`.

You could also use `sizeof(cards[0])` or `sizeof(*cards)` to have the compiler deduce the type from the type of `cards`.

Comment: I would like to add that I don't understand why cards is of type `card_t **` and not `card_t *` in this program (and everything relevant rewritten of course). Saves all kinds of unnecessary allocations.

Comment: @Cheatah: It makes the `qsort` a little more efficient, since each of its swaps only needs to swap two pointers instead of two of the larger `card_t` structures.  Probably not worth the complexity and memory overhead, though.